Config load-balancer Kamailio + FreeSwitch for large conference
I'm using Kamailio and 2 FreeSwitches.
I configured the loadbalance for normal calls and it worked fine.
Use the dispatcher module:
# Dispatch requests
route[DISPATCH] {
    # round robin dispatching on gateways group '1'
    if(!ds_select_dst("1", "4")) {
        send_reply("404", "No destination");
        exit;
    }
    xdbg("--- SCRIPT: going to <$ru> via <$du> (attrs: $xavp(_dsdst_=>attrs))\n");
    t_on_failure("RTF_DISPATCH");
    route(RELAY);
    exit;
}

So for Conference, Can use round robin for routing between multiple FreeSwitch?
The client calling the same conference number from 2 FreeSwitch is the same as Trunking between 2 FreeSwitch?
Is there a way to loadbalance a conference with many participants?
Thanks.

Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is nothing but the useless repetition of the tags, which should not be in the title at all. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it's about. The title now says nothing. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask]. Your post itself should be asking a single, specific question related to the code you've posted.

So to have 2 participants in same conference you need to have them on same freeswitch.
I don't know how big conference you need, but in theory one freeswitch should be enough for quite a big conference.
So you task would be to route participants of same conference to same server, but in this case you probably would need to change algorithm used to select the destination.
Other option would be to route round robin or using other algorithm and then if call hits wrong freeswitch redirect or call freeswitch we need, that probably would need more logic to be written in some scripts.

I use htable to storage conference list. If it not existed, use dispatcher module to route new call.
